# Can I remove 'read' access over user home folders and all website folders under /var/www without breaking anything big?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, users, nginx

If the permissions for all the webroot folders (under /var/www) is 754, can I make it to 750 without breaking my websites or any other thing?

In other words, with background detail: I've 4-5 wordpress websites running in my Ubuntu Virtual Server (on DOcean). Now I want to create a new website in the same server with the help of a friend. For this I'm planning to create a new (non-sudo) username for my friend. He'll be able to use that user for FTP access and terminal access.

Since I don't want him to be able to see other running websites names/folders (and perhaps other users names/folders also), can I restrict/remove the 'read' access for 'other/world' from all the folders under 'www' folder and all folders under '/home' folder, without breaking anything big?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into `/home/`, the individual home directories should have 0750 permissions already.

Regardless, you should be safe to lock the folders down as described without any issues.  I'm forgetting which user/group nginx runs as (I think www-data?) but make sure that its user and/or group has read/execute access on `/var/www/`

Comment: Although you replied very to the point and cleared much of the doubts. But to be double sure, I checked and found that /home/someusername directory(ies) have 755 permissions. But as you told (I'd like to be reassured) I can change all home folders and all folders under /var/www to the 750 (the emphasis being on the last '0') permissions without harming anything/any website.